# LocalActivityManager showing warning and Unable to Use TabHost in Activity- Application Stop when trying to Add Tab

Tags: android, tabs

What is error in this? I am getting warning on LocalActivityManager as:

> The type LocalActivityManager is deprecated

Here is the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.LocalActivityManager; **// Showing Cancel Warning**
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TabHost;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {


TabHost tabHost;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
LocalActivityManager mLocalActivityManager; **// Showing Cancel Warning**

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initTabs(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchResume(); 
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchPause(isFinishing());
    super.onPause();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void initTabs(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);     // The activity TabHost
    mLocalActivityManager = new LocalActivityManager(this, false);
    mLocalActivityManager.dispatchCreate(savedInstanceState);
    tabHost.setup(mLocalActivityManager);

    TabHost.TabSpec spec;                               // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
    Intent intent;                                      // Reusable Intent for each tab        

    intent = new Intent("com.plastemart.plastemartandroid");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("text").setIndicator("Latest")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);      **// Getting Error Unfortunitly Application Stopped...Why?**

    intent = new Intent("com.plastemart.plastemartandroid");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("text").setIndicator("Latest")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    intent = new Intent("com.plastemart.plastemartandroid");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("text").setIndicator("Latest")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    intent = new Intent("com.plastemart.plastemartandroid");
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("text").setIndicator("Latest")
                  .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);

    tabHost.setCurrentTab(4);
}
```

My XML is as below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="36dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_plastemart_title" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Plastemart.Com"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />
</RelativeLayout>


<TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:scrollbars="none" >

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </TabWidget>
            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tab3"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Where I am wrong? I am beginner in Android. Please Explain in Details if found solution.
I wrote above code by finding steps and solution on internet, but I am stucked here from past 4 days.
Please Help me.

Answer (score 3):

This class was deprecated in API level 13. It is recommended to use Fragment and FragmentManager. If you not planning to use Fragment and FragmentManager APIs then you need to live with this warning message.

Please understand that this is a warning message only and not an error message. So you can still live with this. But recommended option is to use Fragment and FragmentManager APIs

You can see more details about the deprecated class here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LocalActivityManager.html

Fragment - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html
FragmentManager - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html